# How to fix linker error "mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL"?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, linker, sdl

I am trying to build `SDL` for use with Eclipse.  I am trying to remove this linker error:

```
Beginning Compilation

21:15:53 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project CMD ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\include\\SDL2" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\CMD.o" "..\\src\\CMD.cpp" 
g++ -o CMD.exe "src\\CMD.o" -lmingw32 -lSDL -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

ERROR(s):

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
21:15:54 Build Finished (took 1s.36ms)
```

The [most pertinent SO archive source I researched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748878/sdl-linker-error-on-mingw-msys-ld-exe-cannot-find-lsdl--) didn't seem to have an actionable answer for my problem, though it had the exact same problem/error:
title --
producing the same error message:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL.
```

If you click to the authors "solution" for the same error as mine its not clear to me how he solved it.

Any help?

Comment: Where do you have your `libSDL2.a` and/or `libSDL2.dll.a`? You passed path for headers (with `-I` compiler flag) but not path to libraries directory (`-L` flag during linking phase).

Comment: libSDL2.a and libSDL2.dll.a are both found c:/MinGW/lib

Comment: Ok, my bad for reading carelessly, why on earth you linking both `SDL` and `SDL2`? They are not compatible.

Comment: You nailed it:I had several errors that by using the following patch resolved them left only the error we are dealing with:Select project Project>Properties

C/C++ Build>Settings ­ Tool Settings>GCC C Compiler ­ Include paths (l)>"/usr/include/SDL" C/C++ Build>Settings ­ Tool Settings>GCC C Linker ­ Libraries (­l)>"SDL" Apply ...then build project and run...BUT now I see I was using SDL instead of SDL2. Should I reinstall with SDL2 and make it compatible, then see if project will link?

Comment: Once again, you cannot use both SDL and SDL2 in one binary.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm feeling like the stooge whose running around with a vase over his head and can't see it: where do you see the SDL and SDL2 in one binary. Ok I found it...I just posted it, duh. Will work with th is and repost.

Comment: Alright, recompiling  and making sure to leave out the SDL resulted in a clean compile but I am now crashing on launch. I've removed everything inside the brackets ruling out software issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703926/using-sdl2-with-g-mingw-crashes-on-launch How does he get the answer?

Comment: flawless execution...using the wrong SDL2.dll. Can someone help with that?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, SDL2 awesome. Ok:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> cannot find -lSDL

Reinstallation of SDL2 avoiding binary conflict between SDL files and SDL2 files as [keltar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744720/keltar) mentioned resolved the immediate problem, and the project built with no errors!

Fixing what was in the braces unmasked a new problem: crashing.

I stripped the program to bare bones and concluded the crashing was outside of the code since it was occurring even without code.

To solve the new problem you would need to go the SDL2 distribution file (the one copied to MinGW) and copy the `SDL2.dll` from it [DLL from distributable][1]--- by dragging the file over your debug and/or release folders where the `.exe file` is (.exe + dll -> right?) [moving dll to exes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq5WC.png).

Build/Run the program and it should work!

You should see a Welcome message!
https://www.caveofprogramming.com/c-for-complete-beginners/setting-up-sdl-windows.html